# How to add STRIPE order confirmation and remember the form data?

Tags: php, html, stripe-payments

I'm trying to add payment methods on my site. such as stripe. the problem is that it works like this: the customer registers for the event (entering name, surname etc) and should then pay and take me from my .html to checkout.php and then if the payment is successful he should remember what he entered in the previous form (html ) and send me the data to the processQrcode.php file. but it doesn't do this. I don't know how to move

```js
<?php
require_once 'init.php';
require_once 'config.php';

$stripe_secret_key = "sk_test_*****5";

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe_secret_key);

session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Recupera i dati inviati tramite il form
    $formData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

    // Esegui la tua logica per gestire i dati
    // ...

    // Memorizza temporaneamente i dati del form in una variabile di sessione
    $_SESSION['form_data'] = $formData;

    // Invia una risposta JSON (puoi personalizzare questa risposta)
    echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
    exit();
}

$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'success_url' => 'https://www.chesifastasera.com/vendor/stripe-php-master/processaQrcode.php',
    'line_items' => [
        [
            'quantity' => 1,
            'price_data' => [
                'currency' => 'EUR',
                'unit_amount' => 20000,
                'product_data' => [
                    'name' => 'SerataTest'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'payment_intent_data' => [
        'metadata' => [
            'custom_data' => 'your_custom_data',  // Puoi aggiungere dati personalizzati qui se necessario
        ],
    ],
]);

http_response_code(303);
header("Location: " . $checkout_session->url);
?>
```

```html
<form id="registrationForm" action="checkout.php" method="post">
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" required><br>

    <label for="cognome">Cognome:</label>
    <input type="text" name="cognome" id="cognome" required><br>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required><br>

    <label for="telefono">Numero di Telefono:</label>
    <input type="tel" name="telefono" id="telefono" required><br>

    <label for="SerataNome">Serata scelta:</label>
    <select name="discoteca" id="SerataNome">
        <option value="SavageePuzzle">SAVAGE & PUZZLE</option>
    </select><br>

    <label for="faiTavolo">Fai tavolo? Siete in Lista quindi questa scelta non è possibile:</label>
    <select name="faiTavolo" id="faiTavolo" required>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select><br>

    <label for="saltaCoda">Vuoi il salta coda?</label>
    <select name="saltaCoda" id="saltaCoda" required>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="Si">Si</option>
    </select><br>

    <label for="quantitaPersone">Quantità di persone:</label>
    <input type="number" name="quantitaPersone" id="quantitaPersone" min="1" value="1" required><br>

    <label for="ricordaWhatsapp">Possiamo ricordarti via WhatsApp l'accredito?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ricordaWhatsapp" id="ricordaWhatsapp"><br>

    <!-- Aggiungi il blocco JavaScript di controllo delle parole non consentite -->
    <script>
        // Definisci la funzione contieneParoleNonConsentite
        function contieneParoleNonConsentite(input, paroleNonConsentite) {
            const inputInMinuscolo = input.toLowerCase();
            for (const parola of paroleNonConsentite) {
                if (inputInMinuscolo.includes(parola)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        // Applica la funzione ai vari campi
        const campiDaControllare = ['nome', 'cognome', 'email'];

        for (const campo of campiDaControllare) {
            document.getElementById(campo).addEventListener('input', function () {
                const inputValore = this.value;
                const paroleNonConsentite = ['porno', 'cazzo', 'merda', 'diomerda', 'stronzo', 'bastardo', 'coglione', 'puttana', 'pompinara', 'suca', 'succhiamelo', 'bastarda', 'vaffanculo', 'deficiente', 'cagare', 'puttana', 'pirla', 'frocio', 'lesbica', 'pompino', 'bocchino', 'cesso', 'sfigato'];

                if (contieneParoleNonConsentite(inputValore, paroleNonConsentite)) {
                    alert('Non puoi inserire una parola non consentita.');
                    this.value = ''; // Cancella il campo se viene inserita una parola non consentita
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <label for="archiviazioneDati">Archiviazione dei dati * <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></label>
    <select name="archiviazioneDati" id="archiviazioneDati" required>
        <option value="AUTORIZZO">AUTORIZZO</option>
        <option value="NON AUTORIZZO">NON AUTORIZZO</option>
    </select><br>

    <label for="invioPromozioni">Invio di informazioni di carattere promozionale e commerciale <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></label>
    <select name="invioPromozioni" id="invioPromozioni" required>
        <option value="AUTORIZZO">AUTORIZZO</option>
        <option value="NON AUTORIZZO">NON AUTORIZZO</option>
    </select><br>

    <!-- Blocco JavaScript per il controllo dei cambiamenti nei dropdown -->
    <script>
        function checkAuthorization() {
            const archiviazioneDati = document.getElementById('archiviazioneDati').value;
            const invioPromozioni = document.getElementById('invioPromozioni').value;

            if (archiviazioneDati === 'NON AUTORIZZO' || invioPromozioni === 'NON AUTORIZZO') {
                alert('Devi autorizzare l\'archiviazione dei dati per poter procedere.');
                document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = true; // Disabilita il pulsante Invia
            } else {
                document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = false; // Abilita il pulsante Invia
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('archiviazioneDati').addEventListener('change', checkAuthorization);
        document.getElementById('invioPromozioni').addEventListener('change', checkAuthorization);
    </script>

    <!-- Aggiungi questa parte solo se il pagamento è immediato -->

    <br>

    <div id="warningMessage">
        Per favore, cliccare solo una volta il tasto "Invia" e attendere il caricamento. Altrimenti l'accredito non verrà fatto. Grazie.
    </div>
    <div id="loadingMessage" style="display: none;">
        Caricamento in corso...
    </div>

    <!-- Aggiungi i campi nascosti per Stripe Checkout -->
    <input type="hidden" name="discoteca" value="SAVAGE & PUZZLE">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2000">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="SerataTest">


<script>
    var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_*******");

    document.getElementById('mainForm').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Crea una sessione di Checkout su Stripe
    fetch('checkout.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            nome: document.getElementById('nome').value,
            cognome: document.getElementById('cognome').value,
            email: document.getElementById('email').value,
            telefono: document.getElementById('telefono').value,
            discoteca: document.getElementById('SerataNome').value,
            faiTavolo: document.getElementById('faiTavolo').value,
            saltaCoda: document.getElementById('saltaCoda').value,
            quantitaPersone: document.getElementById('quantitaPersone').value,
            ricordaWhatsapp: document.getElementById('ricordaWhatsapp').checked,
            archiviazioneDati: document.getElementById('archiviazioneDati').value,
            invioPromozioni: document.getElementById('invioPromozioni').value,
        }),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(session => {
        // Reindirizza a Checkout solo se la sessione è stata creata con successo
        if (session.id) {
            var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51OWirXLdOaRkelq7e41bzMCHiHQQ8DM58BMQ1OOsep64ge470Kf45kjHaav6DSDH3blukq8vozEQK1Dfk4H80bqC000HPnvHxo");
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
        } else {
            // Mostra un messaggio di errore se la creazione della sessione non è riuscita
            alert('Errore durante la creazione della sessione di checkout.');
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        // Mostra un messaggio di errore generico
        alert('Si è verificato un errore durante il pagamento.');
    });
});

</script>

    <button type="submit">PAGA</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What information are you trying to preserver where? How do these pieces fit together? You need to debug the pieces step by step and figure out where the data is dropping more specifically to get assistance.

Comment: Basically the steps are that the customer who registers for the event and enters name, surname, email and telephone number at the end of this clicks on the pay button and transfers it to the stripe php checkout page to enter the payment data if the payment is successful it should recover the data you entered on the previous page and send it to a file called processaQrcode php file. This file creates the qr and saves the customer data in the db.@NolanH

Comment: So the steps are setupyouparty.html (enter the data in the event registration form) and click on pay —> checkout.php (I pay) stripe —> if the payment is successful, send the filled in data (setupyouparty.html) and send them to processaQrcode.php@NolanH